# Let $a$ and $b$ be two elements in a commutative ring $R$ and $(a, b) = R$, show that $(a^m, b^n) = R$ for any positive integers $m$ and $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I stumbled across a question that I have no idea how to start.

I know the questions asking to show that the multiples of $a$ and $b$ as an ordered pair make still make the whole ring.

Any sort of hints or suggestions to start? I don't really want an complete solution, just some sort of hint to start the question.

Thank you!

Comment: How for example does $(1,x^2)$ generate $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: The ideal generated by $(1,x^2)$ already includes $1$, and as ideals absorb multiplication, we must have $\Bbb Z[x]\subseteq (1,x^2)$.

Comment: So the question would better read if $(a,b)$ is the unit ideal the so too is $(a^n,b^m)$.

Answer (score 2):

Write $1$ as a linear combination of $a$ and $b$.  Then raise both sides to the $m+n$ power.

Comment: Woops, I made a mistake. It's supposed to be $(a^m, b^n)$. I don't know if your idea still applies though.

Comment: It does, just apply a power high enough so that each factor has either $a^m$ or $b^n$.

Comment: By factor I meant term.

Comment: Hmm, I'll try it out. Just wondering though, why do you write $1$ as a linear combination of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Because $(x,y)=1$ iff $1$ is a linear combination of $x$ and $y$.  The end result should be to show that $1$ is also a linear combination of $a^m$ and $b^n$.

Answer (score 0):

The condition $(a,b) = R$ is equivalent to saying that $\overline{b}$ is invertible in $R/(a)$. Now, what can you say about $\overline{b}^m$?

Comment: Hey, I have no idea what $\overline{b}$ is. So I can't really answer your question haha.

Comment: Okay, this answer isn't useful to you if you don't know about quotient rings.